# sed -i doesent work on MacOs (sed: 1) and work on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, command-line

I succeeded to use sed -i on Linux to modify a JSON value in a file.

```
$> sed -i '/brand/c\   \"brand\": \"'valueModified'\"' ./config/brand.config.json
```

But on MacOS I get:

> sed: 1: "./config/brand.config.json": invalid command code .

I'm trying to use this command in a shell script on linux and macOS.

Thank you

Comment: Does `man sed` on the Mac mention the `-i` option at all?

Comment: On OSX use `sed -i.bak '...'`

Answer (score 0):

POSIX `sed` implementations allow for the I line replacement where non-POSIX UNIX implementations do not. OSX, like BSD implentations can be accomplished like so :

```
cp -p ./config/brand.config.json ./config/brand.config.json.tmp;
sed '/brand/c\   \"brand\": \"'valueModified'\"' ./config/brand.config.json.tmp > ./config/brand.config.json
```